# Graphics.drawString overlapping previous character

Tags: java, image, graphics, awt

I was trying to achieve dynamic text on top and bottom of the image. Below is the output right now I am able to produce, but the characters in the bottom line getting overlapped each other. Please tell me where I went wrong in my code:

[image]

**code snippet running to generate image as in the image:**

```
package com.logogenerator.util;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class CurvedText {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoninvertibleTransformException {
        try {

            final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("E://xxx.png"));
            Graphics2D g;
            g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

            drawCircleTextTop("ABCDEFGH", image, g);
            drawCircleTextBottom("ABCDEFGH", image, g);

            g.dispose();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("E://Boathouse-WorkSpace//testboth.png"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Flip Down and writing the text 
     * @param s String to be written on the image
     * @param image Buffered image on which string to be written
     * @param g Graphics 2D object to access the Buffered Image
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws NoninvertibleTransformException
     */
    private static void drawCircleTextTop(String s, BufferedImage image, Graphics2D g) throws IOException, NoninvertibleTransformException {  

        if(image != null){

            Dimension cd = new Dimension(256,256);
            Point pt = new Point(cd.width / 2, cd.height / 2);
            int radius = 100;


            String st = s;
            Point center = pt;
            double r = radius;
            double charDegree = 5;
            double a1 = Math.toRadians(360 - (s.length()/2 * charDegree ));//-Math.PI/4;
            double af = 1.0;


            double curangle = a1;
            Point2D c = new Point2D.Double(center.x, center.y);
            char ch[] = st.toCharArray();
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            AffineTransform xform1, cxform;
            xform1 = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(c.getX(),c.getY());
            for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
                double cwid = (double)(getWidth(ch[i],fm));
                if (!(ch[i] == ' ' || Character.isSpaceChar(ch[i]))) {
                    cwid = (double)(fm.charWidth(ch[i]));
                    cxform = new AffineTransform(xform1);
                    cxform.rotate(curangle, 0.0, 0.0);
                    String chstr = new String(ch, i, 1);
                    g.setTransform(cxform);
                    g.drawString(chstr, (float)(-cwid/2), (float)(-r));
                }

                // compute advance of angle assuming cwid<
                if (i < (ch.length - 1)) {
                    double adv = cwid/2.0 + fm.getLeading() + getWidth(ch[i + 1],fm)/2.0;
                    curangle += Math.sin(adv / r);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Flip Down and writing the text 
     * @param s String to be written on the image
     * @param image Buffered image on which string to be written
     * @param g Graphics 2D object to access the Buffered Image
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws NoninvertibleTransformException
     */
    private static void drawCircleTextBottom(String s, BufferedImage image, Graphics2D g) throws IOException, NoninvertibleTransformException {  

        if(image != null){

            Dimension cd = new Dimension(256,256);
            Point pt = new Point(cd.width / 2, cd.height / 2);
            int radius = 100;

            String st = s;
            Point center = pt;
            double r = radius;
            double charDegree = 4;
            double a1 = Math.toRadians(360 - (s.length()/2 * charDegree ));//-Math.PI/4;
            double af = 1.0;



            double curangle = a1;
            Point2D c = new Point2D.Double(center.x, center.y);
            char ch[] = st.toCharArray();
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            AffineTransform xform1, cxform;
            xform1 = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(c.getX(),c.getY());
//            for(int i = ch.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
            for(int i = ch.length-1; i >-1; i--) {
                double cwid = (double)(getWidth(ch[i],fm));
                if (!(ch[i] == ' ' || Character.isSpaceChar(ch[i]))) {
                    cwid = (double)(fm.charWidth(ch[i]));
                    cxform = new AffineTransform(xform1); 
                    cxform.rotate(curangle, 0.0, 0.0);
                    String chstr = new String(ch, i, 1);
                    g.setTransform(cxform);
                    g.drawString(chstr, (float)(cwid/2), (float)(r));
//                    System.out.println("Curve Angle :"+curangle);
//                    System.out.println("Cwid : "+cwid);
                }

                // compute advance of angle assuming cwid<
                if (i < (ch.length - 1)) {
                    double adv = cwid/2.0 + fm.getLeading() + getWidth(ch[i + 1],fm)/2.0;
                    curangle += Math.sin((adv / r));
                }
            }

        }
    }

    static int getWidth(char c, FontMetrics fm) {
        if (c == ' ' || Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
            return fm.charWidth('n');
        }
            else {
            return fm.charWidth(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my approach?

Comment: I am resolving this issue by adding some extra " " - spaces at last of the string, then its working fine. But it's not seems to be the solution, some issue is there in the approach.

Comment: `final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("E://xxx.png"));`  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to be found by drawing a circle around the center at the same `radius` as the letters.

[image]

The angle is chosen in order to separate the letters at the given radius. But while they are drawn **outside** the circle at the top (adding extra space at the top of the letter), they're drawn **inside** the circle at the bottom (removing space at the top of the letter - crowding them together).